# Mysql table does not accept any update request

Tags: mysql

I am using `Server version: 5.6.27-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)` and I have a problem with a table.

I tried to update some fields with a GUI software, but when I came back to the command line, the lines I tried to update where not updated.

I tried to see if the table was locked using `SHOW OPEN TABLES` as stated in various other questions. But my table does not appear to be locked:

```
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
| Database           | Table                                           | In_use | Name_locked |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+

| arcdev             | SCHEDULED_COMMAND                               |      0 |           0 |
```

And as soon as I try to make an update like:

```
UPDATE SCHEDULED_COMMAND SET field = 1;
```

The server just keeps loading and nothing happen. I tried on other tables and everything worked just fine.

I also tried some `DELETE` requests and even a `DROP TABLE` and nothing work so far...

What am I missing?

Thank you for your precious help!

EDIT: Here is the result of the SHOW PROCESSLIST command while a request is hanging:

```
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------+------+----------+-------------------------------+
| Id     | User     | Host                                  | db        | Command | Time | State    | Info                          |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------+------+----------+-------------------------------+
| 282588 | rdsadmin | localhost:17966                       | mysql     | Sleep   |    2 |          | NULL                          |
| 534575 | arc      | XXXXXX:49376                          | arcdev    | Sleep   |   17 |          | NULL                          |
| 534579 | arc      | XXXXXX:49443                          | arcdev    | Query   |    0 | init     | SHOW PROCESSLIST              |
| 534659 | arc      | XXXXXX:49836                          | arcdev    | Query   |   14 | updating | DELETE FROM SCHEDULED_COMMAND |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------+------+----------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you open a second terminal (while the first is hanging) and do SHOW PROCESSLIST?

Comment: just to check but your user of MySQL has permission to update, yes?

Comment: @WolfgangStengel I edited my question with the SHOW PROCESSLIST command. Martin, yes it worked just fine before that.

Comment: I waited long enough to get an error message: ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: This means there is another session with an outstanding lock on the table. It should show up in the processlist, so it's undoubtedly one of the two processes doing "Sleep". A process can hold a lock from an earlier SQL query, even if it's not doing any SQL query at the current moment (it will appear with state "Sleep"). So finish your transactions!

Comment: Ok, if I shutdown the connected computer, does that end the transaction? Sorry to be that unprofessional

Comment: Ok, it worked that way, thank you very much for taking the time to help me!